# Can a timer goes faster than 1ms Android

Tags: java, android, timer, frequency

I want to sample sound from an analog device and I use a timer. However, with Android API [timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) you can set the wait and delay in milliseconds. For example

```
schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)//period in milliseconds
Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, beginning at the specified time.
```

It means that I cannot go faster than 1ms (i.e., 1kHz).

Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is True. It's a System defined time period.